# Metadata-generation-failed error when installing Turtle on VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module, pip, turtle-graphics

I tried to install turtle on my VS Code and got this error message, could you guys tell me what's going on with this module, please?

[image: error]

Answer (score 2):

Turtle is already included in the Python standard library. I am assuming that pip is trying to install a different package than you are looking for and your geting an error

[Turtle](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/turtle.html)

Answer (score 1):

Which turtle do you want to install?

If you mean this package, then you don't need to do any installation.

[image]

It already exists when you install Python.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys, got that part about turtle being a package already existing in Python. So why can't I run Pong as in this video? -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGf2GcyHPhc&list=PL3bqcU21UEmHMDc6w5gFS-SIpWeQQwoZz&index=70&t=573s